# Ajax in Laravel 5.3 : GET method not allowed (405 error)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a list of animals profiles (ID cards). When I click on one of them while logged in as an Admin, I access a page with more details and several pictures. There, I can edit the animal profile (POST method), and I would also like to be able to delete a picture by clicking on it. I'm trying to use Ajax to do that, but I'm unable to complete the process. My code so far :

```
Route::get('/edition-adoption/{animal}', 'AnimalsController@editAdoption')
    ->where('animal', '[0-9]+');

Route::post('/edition-adoption/{animal}', 'AnimalsController@updateAdoption');

Route::get('/edition-adoption/{folder}/{file}/delete', ['uses' => 'AnimalsController@deletePicture', 'as' => 'delete']);
```

View :

```
<form role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url('/edition-adoption/{animal}') }} ">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

 /*several fields to update*/

            <div class="col-xs-11">
                <?php
                    edit_profile($animal->id);
                ?>
                <script src={{asset("/js/imageSrc.js")}}></script>
            </div> 
     /*other fields & submit button*/ </form>
```

Controller :

```
public function editAdoption (Animal $animal) {
    return view('administration/edition-adoption',['animal' => $animal]);
}

public function deletePicture($file, $folder) {
    $path = public_path('js/slider_images/Adoption/Profile/'.$folder.'/'.$file);
    unlink($path);
}

public function updateAdoption (Request $request) {
    /*several update requests*/
}
```

Helper :

```
function edit_profile($current_id) {


            $paths = File::Files('js/slider_images/Adoption/Profile/'.$current_id);

       if (count($paths)==0) {
        echo 
        "<p>Aucune image</p>";
       }    
           else {
        foreach($paths as $path)
                {
                $filesinfo[] = pathinfo($path);
                }

               foreach ($filesinfo as $file) {

                $current_basename = $file['basename'];

                echo 
                "<img onclick='getImgSrc(this)' width='200px' src='".asset("/js/slider_images/Adoption/Profile/".$current_id."/".$current_basename)."'/>&nbsp&nbsp";
                }
       }
}
```

imageSrc.js (Ajax) :

```
    function getImgSrc(param){

var imgSrc = $(param).attr("src");
var myarr = imgSrc.split("/");
var arrlen = myarr.length;
var id = myarr[arrlen-2];
var myvar = myarr[arrlen-1];
var result = confirm("Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer cette image ? Cette action est irréversible.");

if (result) {

    $.ajax({
          url: 'delete',
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
          data: {'folder': id, 'file' : myvar},
          success: function (response) {
             alert('Image supprimée !');
          },
          error: function () {
             alert('Erreur. Veuillez réessayer.');
          }
        });
    }
}
```

The confirmation alert works fine, but when I click on OK, the following exception appear :

> GET
>   http://localhost/sites/(...)/public/edition-adoption/delete?folder=foldername&file=filename.jpg
>   405 (Method Not Allowed)

Any idea(s) on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try passing the full relative url in your ajax. Your route is `/edition-adoption/{folder}/{file}/delete'`, but it's accessing `/edition-adoption/delete?`

Comment: @aynber thank you for your answer. I tried using `url: id+'/'+myvar+'/delete',` but the result is the same...

Comment: check what your `artisan route:list | grep edition-adoption | grep delete` says.

Comment: @AlexBlex : `$ php artisan route:list | grep edition-adoption | grep delete` gives me the following lines : `|        | GET|HEAD | edition-adoption/{folder}/{file}/delete | delete               | App\Http\Controllers\AnimalsController@deletePicture                   | web          |
`

Comment: Cool, so `curl  http://localhost/sites/(...)/public/edition-adoption/foldername/filename.jpg/delete -v 2>&1 | head -20`  should delete the image. Could you confirm if it returns 405 response ?

Comment: @AlexBlex Actually... it returns a 404 response :-/

Comment: Heh, seems like a good time to look at logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it thanks to a friend. It appears the order of the parameters (`$folder`, `$file`) in the Controller mattered. They were in the expected order for the url/route (`/edition-adoption/{folder}/{file}/delete`), BUT they were swapped in the path (I expected  `http://localhost/sites/(...)/public/edition-adoption/foldern‌​ame/filename.jpg/del‌​ete` and got  `http://localhost/sites/(...)/public/edition-adoption/filen‌​ame.jpg/foldername/del‌​ete`; which explained the 404 error). I changed `public function deletePicture($file, $folder)` to `public function deletePicture($folder, $file)` and now it works fine! I also added `$(param).hide();` in the Ajax success to hide the deleted picture without having to refresh the page. Anyway, thanks to @aynber and @AlexBlex for their advice!